# Is StreamReader.Read() a blocking method?

Tags: c#, streamreader, networkstream

Is `StreamReader.Read()` a blocking method especially if applied to a `NetworkStream`?

Comment: It is synchronous if that's what you mean, if you are using .net 4.5 then you can use `ReadAync()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - it blocks until one of the follow conditions is satisfied:

- A character is read
- The end of the underlying stream is reached
- The underlying stream throws an exception

Comment: The documentation states that "ReadBlock is a blocking version of Read." which implies that Read is non-blocking. Perhaps there is an issue with the definition of "blocking"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kstw824(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SimonSvensson: I believe that's a version which will *only* return when either it's read as many characters as it's been asked to or the stream end has been reached - i.e. it won't return a "partial" result when there's potentially more data coming.